# Desserializar una propiedad dinámica en una ASP.net web-api

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, serialización

Edit: añado array a los objetos Json ya que el caso real incluye arrays.

Tengo una clase `element`que contiene una propiedad `options`, la classe de options puede a su vez cambiar sus propiedades por ejemplo podría tener estos 2

```
   element1 = {
            "id":"1",
            "options":{
                "margenes":["24px","25px","0px","32px"], 
                "printable":"true",
                "stackOverflow":"great"
                }
            }

   element2 = {
            "id":"2",
            "options":{
                "question":"awsome",
                "propertyDiferent":"empty"
                }
            }
```

en la web api tengo un metodo asi:

```
public object Post([FromBody] Element element)
    {
        SaveToMongo(element);
    }
```

la clase element:

```
public class Element
{
    public dynamic options { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}
```

Cuando recojo el Element desde mongo no tengo problemas. Pero cuando he de enviarlo mediante el metodo post de la web Api no se deserializa en un expando object como lo hace desde mongo. ¿Cómo podría conseguir un comportamiento similar en los dos extremos?

Básicamente quiero que el paso del objeto por la web api no me suponga un esfuerzo la web-api la he creado simplemente por no ser capaz de atacar a mongo desde javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primer paso, hacer que la llamada `ajax`desde javascript pase el JSON en forma de string, de lo contrario la propiedad dinámica options no se rellena.

```
element.options = element.options.toString();
```

Así tengo un string JSON que aunque se guarda en el mongo lo puedo recuperar sin que se modifique. Pero para poder devolverlo en la Api lo he de deserializar antes de la deserialización que hace el propio controller.

```
element.options = JObject.Parse(element.options);
```

Es un sistema poco elegante, con unas cuantas desventajas, como que no permite el tratamiento de options en mongo. Pero ha sido la única manera en la que he logrado que el paso por el mongo no modificara el objeto.

Answer (score 1):

EDITO:

Si lo que necesitas es un `ExpandoObject` simplemente necesitas declarar el objeto principal como `dynamic` para así poder tratarlo como un Expando, de la otra manera creo que no se puede mezclar la serialización directa a una clase con un ExpandoObject de por medio. Por lo que la solucion sería declarar la firma del controlador de la WebApi tal que así:

```
public object Post([FromBody] dynamic elementExpando)
{

}
```

ANTIGUO:

Si quieres serializarlo deberás saber la opciones que puedes llegar a recibir, aunque no siempre las recibas.

Por ello deberás crear una nueva clase `Options` que recoja las propiedades que pueden llegar y además modificar tu clase `Element` para que la propiedad options sea del nuevo tipo creado.

Tu clase quedaría tal que así:

```
public class Element
{
    public Options options { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}

public class Options
{
    public bool printable { get; set; }
    public string stackOverflow { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string propertyDiferent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Precisamente quiero evitar eso. No quiero que cada nueva opción que aparezca tener que cambiarla en varios sitios. Quiero que la web api sea simplemente un paso para acceder al mongo, que no me implique desarrollo a cada cambio.

Comment: Entonces necesitarías declarar el objeto entero como dynamic

Comment: Aún poniendo el objeto entero como dynamic solo me llega `{object}`

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic` no tiene un tipo de dato concreto y por tanto el deserializador no puede saber a que va a convertirlo(por algo el nombre `dynamic`, ¿no?). Tienes que utilizar un tipo de dato concreto, definido, que sea posible obtener toda la metadata para el deserializador funcionar.

`Dictionary<string,string>` es tu mejor opcion ya que es la representacion de un objeto en la notacion json.

Puedes utilizar [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para deserializar el objeto y convertirlo a la clase `Element`.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Element
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<String,string> Options { get; set; }

  public static Element FromJSON(String jsonString)
  {
      Element e = new Element();
      dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
      Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject options = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)data.options;


     e.id = data.id;
     e.Options = new Dictionary<String,String>();
     foreach (var item in options)
     {
        e.Options.Add(item.Key, item.Value.Value<string>(item.Key));           
     }

     return e;
  }
}
```

Uso:

```
string json = @"{
                'id':'2',
                'options':{
                    'question':'awsome',
                    'propertyDiferent':'empty'
                    }
             }";
Element e = Element.FromJSON(json);
```

No afirmo que ese codigo te vaya a funcionar en tu caso. Pero ya tienes una alternativa.

Comment: Pero por ejemplo el desserializador del driver de mongo db, si que deserializa el objeto dynamic correctamente y consigo devolverlo por la web-api sin problema. Me extraña que sea posible usarlo desde y hacia bson y no hacia json ya que no añado ningún tipo extraño.

Comment: Y como añadiría esta conversión a diccionario en la llamada del controller? si pudiera conseguir el json en string me valdría.

Comment: Cuando retornas la data del server al cliente, ¿como te la retorna?

Comment: Estoy intentando pasar del cliente al server. Del server al cliente funciona perfecto. El problema es que al hacer la llamada post en options me llega un `{object}` tal como lo muestra el debugger